# Displaying the values from json response to dropdown list

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a JSON respone from REST API . I need to move the values of countries, states and cities into my drop down. My default value will be **ALL**. I need to push these countries, states and and cities' values in there respective drop downs along with ALL as first value by default.

My output comes as `[ALL , Delhi]` missing Bangalore.

Response:

```
 Geography : [{"countryname":"India","state":[{"statename":"Delhi",
"cities":[{"city":"Delhi"}]},{"statename":"Karnataka",
"cities":[{"city":"Bangalore"}]}]}]
```

HTML :

```
<form class="form-row " role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-14" for="groupz">Country*</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCountry" name="country" ng-change="GetCountry(model.selectedCountry)">
       <option ng-repeat=" item in model.countries track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="groupz">State*</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedState" name="state" ng-change="GetState(model.selectedState)" ng-disabled="model.selectedCountry == 'ALL'">
<option ng-repeat="item in model.states track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option> </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-20" for="groupz">City*</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="model.selectedCity" name="city" ng-change="GetCity(model.selectedCity)" ng-disabled="model.selectedState == 'ALL' || model.selectedCountry== 'ALL'">
    <option ng-repeat="item in model.cities track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
UserService.Geography(json).then(function(response) {

if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success') {
    var geography = response.json.response.geography;
    console.log("Geography : " + JSON.stringify(geography));


    $scope.model.countries = [];
    $scope.model.countries.push("ALL");

    for (var i = 0; i < geography.length; i++) {

        console.log(geography.length);



        $scope.model.countries.push(geography[i].countryname);
        console.log($scope.model.countries);

        if (($scope.model.countries != []) || ($scope.model.countries != null)) {

            console.log($scope.model.countries.length);

            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.model.countries.length; j++) {

                $scope.model.states = [];
                $scope.model.states.push("ALL");
                $scope.model.states.push(geography[i].state[i].statename);
                console.log($scope.model.states);

                if (($scope.model.states != []) || ($scope.model.states != null)) {

                    console.log($scope.model.states.length);
                    for (var k = 0; k < $scope.model.states.length; k++) {
                        $scope.model.cities = [];
                        $scope.model.cities.push("ALL");
                        $scope.model.cities.push(geography[i].state[i].cities[i].city);
                        console.log($scope.model.cities);

                        if (($scope.model.cities != []) || ($scope.model.cities != null)) {

                            $scope.model.segments = [];
                            var segments = "_ALL";

                            $scope.model.segments.push(segments);
                            console.log($scope.model.segments);

                        }
                    }
                    $scope.model.selectedCity = $scope.model.cities[0];
                }
            }
            $scope.model.selectedState = $scope.model.states[0];
        }
    }
    $scope.model.selectedCountry = $scope.model.countries[0];
}});
}
$scope.model.selectedCountry is the country selected by user in dropdown.
```

Comment: Can u please tell what problem you are facing

Comment: Hi , I am just getting [ALL , Delhi] not bangalore .

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really buggy and you have used `i` indexer inside nested loops where you were supposed to use the `j` and `k` indexer.

So I rewrote the code with the help of `angular.forEach` to increase the code's readability as well.

Please have a look. I have tested it at my end as well.

```
$scope.model = {
        countries: ["ALL"],
        states: ["ALL"],
        cities: ["ALL"]
    };

    angular.forEach(geography, function(value, key) {
        var country = value;
        $scope.model.countries.push(country.countryname);

        if (country.state != null && country.state.length > 0) {

            angular.forEach(country.state, function(value, key) {
                var state = value;
                $scope.model.states.push(state.statename);

                if (state.cities != null && state.cities.length > 0) {

                    angular.forEach(state.cities, function(value, key) {
                        var city = value;
                        $scope.model.cities.push(city.city);
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

It will be easy to understand but I am going to explain still what I did. First you need to push `ALL` in all three arrays `countries`, `cities` and `states`.

So I wrote an object with already initialized arrays containing `ALL` string in all three arrays.

- The geography array is traversed
- It will push the current country name into countries array
- It then checks that whether this country has any state
- If not, it moves ahead else it traverse all states.
- The same sequence is done in case of states and cities.

Hope that clarifies the code. Let me know if you have any questions. Hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sourceJson = [{
  "countryname": "India",
  "state": [{
    "statename": "Delhi",
    "cities": [{
      "city": "Delhi"
    }]
  }, {
    "statename": "Karnataka",
    "cities": [{
      "city": "Bangalore"
    }]
  }]
}];


var countries = new Array();
var states = new Array();
var cities = new Array();

countries.push("ALL");
states.push("ALL");
cities.push("ALL");

for (var i = 0; i < sourceJson.length; i++) {

  countries.push(sourceJson[i].countryname);

  var sourceStates = sourceJson[i].state;

  for (var j = 0; j < sourceStates.length; j++) {

    states.push(sourceStates[j].statename);

    var sourceCities = sourceStates[j].cities;
    for (var k = 0; k < sourceCities.length; k++) {
      cities.push(sourceCities[k].city)

    }

  }

}

console.log(countries);
console.log(states);
console.log(cities);
```